# scalariform not downloading dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, scalariform

When I try to install the scalariform plugin :

build.sbt :

```
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.6.0")
```

I receive sbt error :

[

```
trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.6.0: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 24-Mar-2016 23:51:57
>
```

Do I need a specific version of the scalari plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project structure below works. Seems cannot add a plugin from build.sbt, needs to be in /project/plugins.sbt.

/project/plugins.sbt :

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.6.0")
```

build.sbt :

```
scalariformSettings
```

.scala files need to be in folder src/main/scala in order to be formatted by scalariform